# How to build (and maximize) this equation

Tags: optimization, economics

I'm trying to solve an economics problem but I cannot figure out how to build the equation system, or how to find the maximum in a piecewise function.

A simplified version of the function would be like this:

From 0 to $t_1$:

$X=X(t)$

Then:

$f = X_{t_1} * e^{-r * t_1}$

**I want to find the $t_1$ that maximizes $f$**. The maximum will depend on the function $X(t)$ directly (which in practice will be similar to $ln(x)$), but will be inverse to the $e^{-r * t_1}$ part.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $f(t) = X(t)e^{-rt}$? And how is $X(t)$ defined for $t > t_1$?

Comment: Can you clarify the definition of $f$?  We have $f(t) = X(t)$ for $t \in [0, t_1]$ and $f(t) = X(t_1)e^{-rt_1}$ for $t > t_1$?

Comment: Or is it just that $f(t) = X(t)e^{-rt}$ and you want to maximize $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, it will depend on what $X(t)$ is, but keeping it general, the maximum can be found by finding the critical points. This will include the two endpoints $t=0$ and $t=t_1$. To find the ones in between, take the derivative and find where it equals 0:

$$f'(t)=-r*X(t)e^{-rt}+X'(t)e^{-rt}$$
$$f'(t)=e^{-rt}(X'(t)-rX(t))$$

Now find where the derivative is equal to zero:
$$X'(t) = rX(t)$$

Then just compare the function value at all the critical points. Whichever one is the greatest, is the maximum.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it solves the problem described. I'll rethink the problem (I already did it actually) and post as a separated problem. Thanks!